# Alternative to SharePoint in C# and open source

Tags: sharepoint

Do you know any alternative to SharePoint in C# and open source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DotNetNuke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DotNetNuke) is a CMS, but SharePoint has a lot of features. Frankly speaking I would not be able to recommend any license free software equivalent to SharePoint, but you can try [MetaDot](http://www.metadot.com/) if you just need portal software with CMS features.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you are looking for as an alternative, but [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/)

is pretty awesome

Answer (score 0):

You won't find any open-surce (or proprietary, for that matter) software with all the features of SharePoint. If you are looking for CMS, I've heard good things about [Umbraco](http://umbraco.org/)